Fill <select> element with jQuery
Scenario: When the page is loaded it has e.g. users State in plain div and below there's e.g. address form to be filled, so the existing State select list can be autofilled with correct State and save time.
HTML:
<div class="state-text">
Alabama
</div>

<select class="state">
  <option value="" selected="selected">- Select -</option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
</select>

jQuery:
if ($('.state-text').val() == 'Alabama') {
    $('select.state').val('AL');
} 
else {
    $('select.state').val(''); // default to "- Select -"
}

https://jsfiddle.net/cp2n4dtz/
Reference source If/else else if in Jquery for a condition but it doesn't seem to work. What i missing?
Goal is if .state-text has Alabama, then the right value of AL should be selected, if Alaska then it's AK and so on for all 50 states. On page load.
Thank you.

<div>s do not have values. They have innerText or innerHTML, or in jquery lingo, $('.state-text').text().trim()

@mykaf thank you for the right answer, this solved the problem.
